# split matrices over two lines using array

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I was wondering if there is anyway to split across two lines the following eigenvalue , eigenvector pair which I have listed below? I have tried \bigskip, \par, \newline within the array environment, but these all give me an error (more precisely " missing $ inserted" for which I do not understand). A minimum working example is given below along with a picture of the output. I would like to keep the output I have now, but loose the error which latex gives me. Also, is it possible to add some vertical space after the matrices at the bottom? I tried using \vspace{}, but I did not succeed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openany]{report}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalefnt}   


 Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors \par
(D126) & {\small \begin{equation}
  \left[\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ -d\\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}\,d}{3}\\ \frac{\sqrt{3}\,d} 
 {3} 
  \end{array}\right),   \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & -1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & - 
 \frac{\left(2\,\sqrt{3}+3\right)\,\left(d+3\right)}{3\,\left(d-1\right)} & 
\frac{\left(2\,\sqrt{3}-3\right)\,\left(d+3\right)}{3\,\left(d-1\right)}\\ 1 & 0 & 
 \frac{3\,d+2\,\sqrt{3}\,d+2\,\sqrt{3}+5}{d-1} & \frac{3\,d-2\,\sqrt{3}\,d- 
 2\,\sqrt{3}+5}{d-1}\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right) \right] 
 \nonumber
 \end{equation}} \\ \hline
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably better of defining some letters being equal to those big fractions and then displaying these letters in the matrix. No one want to read it in its current form

Comment: That is not a working example. And the formulas in the not-working example are different from those in the picture.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? (Note that I've gotten rid of all `\left` and `\right` sizing directives and all `\,` spacing directives.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openany]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors D126
\begin{gather*}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.35}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ -d \\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}d}{3} \\  \frac{\sqrt{3}d}{3} 
  \end{pmatrix},  \\[2ex] % <-- induce a line break
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
    1 & 0 
          & -\frac{(2\sqrt{3}+3)(d+3)}{3(d-1)} 
          &  \frac{(2\sqrt{3}-3)(d+3)}{3(d-1)} \\ 
    1 & 0 
          & \frac{3d+2\sqrt{3}d+2\sqrt{3}+5}{d-1} 
          & \frac{3d-2\sqrt{3}d-2\sqrt{3}+5}{d-1} \\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. Just what I was looking for)